# Get mouse location from NSScrollView

Tags: mouseevent, nsscrollview, nswindowcontroller

I have added my `NSScrollView` over the content view of my `NSWindow` object. Now I need to know the mouse location over the scrollview.

I have tried the following. But nothing gives the correct location.

```
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent{
    NSPoint eventLocation = [theEvent locationInWindow];
    NSPoint locationInScroll = [inputScrollView convertPoint:eventLocation toView:nil];
//Both gives the wrong location. 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct, assuming that `inputScrollView` is the document view and the `NSScrollView` itself. 
Another potential problem could be if you change the orientation of the coordinate system in one of the views?